# Computing a neo4j graph database to get combinatory results

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Is it possible to create a graph database to model product features (Phone) and from that model generate all the valid phone combinations?.

I have created a database like this.

```
CREATE
(mobilephone:Phone),
(screen:Component),
(camera:Component),
(lowrescam:Component),
(hirescam:Component),
(flash:Component),

(mobilephone)-[:MANDATORY]->(screen),
(mobilephone)-[:OPTIONAL]->(camera),
(camera)-[:CHOOSE1]->(lowrescam),
(camera)-[:CHOOSE1]->(hirescam),
(camera)-[:REQUIRES]->(flash)


(mobilephone)-[:MANDATORY]->(screen),
(mobilephone)-[:OPTIONAL]->(camera),
(camera)-[:CHOOSE1]->(lowrescam),
(camera)-[:CHOOSE1]->(hirescam),
(camera)-[:REQUIRES]->(flash)
```

I want to be able to get all the valid combinations of a phone given the model.

The result should be:

Product 1:

```
mobilephone,screen
```

Product 2:

```
mobilephone,screen,camera,lowrescam,flash
```

Product 3:

```
mobilephone,screen,camera,hirescam,flash
```

A non valid product is:

```
mobilephone,screen,camera,lowrescam,hirescam,flash
```

This is because the model doesn't allow both camera types with `CHOOSE1`.

The final purpose is to check if feature models can be stored/computed in a graph DB.

I'm new to Neo4j and am researching the possible ways to model behaviour otherwise modeled using a labelled transition system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

What you want to do is a bad idea, since you can't say to Neo4j "Hey, I want every Phone node to have only one relation to a Camera node, and always have a Screen, and...."
Constraints exists in Neo4j, but you can't constraint such a thing.

Neo4j is a database, and as every database should do, it's used to store and use data, not to create data like you want to (create every combination of phone and components using constraints).

This kind of logic should be implemented in your application, and then stored in the database using a good data model (the one I provided seems -not the best but- good)

#### Always use labels

Create nodes like you did is useless since you are just creating empty nodes with no label, no properties. Also, labels help you to ensure good performance.

#### Example

```
CREATE
(mobilephone:Phone),
(screen:Component),
(camera:Component),
(lowrescam:Component),
(hirescam:Component),
(flash:Component),

(mobilephone)-[:MANDATORY]->(screen),
(mobilephone)-[:OPTIONAL]->(camera),
(camera)-[:CHOOSE1]->(lowrescam),
(camera)-[:CHOOSE1]->(hirescam),
(camera)-[:REQUIRES]->(flash)
```

### EDIT

To match your valid phones, you can do it like this:

Product 1 (a phone with only one mandatory item) :

```
Match (phone:Phone)-[:MANDATORY]->(sc:Component)
WHERE count(sc) = 1
return phone
```

Product 2 (a phone)

```
Match (phone:Phone)-[:MANDATORY]->(sc:Component),
(phone)-[:OPTIONAL]->(ca:Component),
(phone)-[:CHOOSE1]->(cam:Component),
(cam)-[:REQUIRES]->(f:Component)
WHERE count(cam) = 1;
RETURN phone, sc, ca, cam, f
```

As you can see, the requests are very specific to each case. I think you may have to reconsider your data model as this one is not a good one I think.

Let me suggest you a better data model:

#### Creation

```
(phone: Phone{name: "Stackoverflow"})
(sc:Screen:Mandatory {name: "LCD blabla HD 1500000p")//The screen is a Screen, and it's a mandatory
(camera:Camera:Unique {name: "Camera"})//The camera must be unique
(flash:Flash{intensity: "1000"})//The flash is just... a flash
(camera)-[Requires]->(flash)
```

#### Queries

Then, you can create your valid combinations with new phones nodes:

```
MATCH (sc:Screen:Mandatory {name: "LCD blabla HD 1500000p")
CREATE (phone:Phone {name: "Example"})-[:USES]->(sc:Screen)
RETURN phone //and here you have your first combination, a phone with just a screen.
```

But as you can see, you'll have to create every combination using your hands and a bunch of requests, a bit painfull.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you asked about a Neo4j solution, but I'd like to offer you another model. As you've phrased it, this sounds like you're in an analysis phase. As such, you might not need a database.

One approach for a model of this domain is as a "feature flow" network where vertices represent "product concerns" and directed edges represent X "has-feature" Y.

Start with source and sink nodes `phone` and `product`.

If a concern X requires another concern Y, there will be a single edge from X to Y. This effectively makes Concern Y "mandatory". If there is an option, there will be more than one outgoing edge from X to, say, Y and Z. The final concerns in the network flow link to the `product` sink node. The combinations of all product features becomes the set of all paths from source to sink.

Here is a sample implementation in Clojure.

The directed acyclic graph is a hash-map with vertices as keys and a vector of vertices as values:

```
(def g
  {:phone [:mobilephone]
   :mobilephone [:screen]
   :screen [:camera :product]
   :camera [:highrescam :lowrescam]
   :highrescam [:flash]
   :lowrescam [:flash]
   :flash [:product]})
```

Visualizing this in yEd, we get:
[image]

As you traverse from left to right in this network, you're building your product feature by feature.

We can find all paths using a depth-first search from source to sink:

```
(defn all-paths [graph source sink]
  (letfn [(dfs [path visited]
            (let [vertex (peek path)]
              (if (= sink vertex) [path]
                  (->> vertex
                       graph
                       (remove visited)
                       (mapcat #(dfs (conj path %) (conj visited %)))))))]
    (dfs [source] #{source})))
```

Invoking with `:phone` as source and `:product` as sink, we get:

```
(all-paths g :phone :product)

([:phone :mobilephone :screen :camera :highrescam :flash :product]
 [:phone :mobilephone :screen :camera :lowrescam :flash :product]
 [:phone :mobilephone :screen :product])
```

Introducing touchscreen and keyboard options for the phone input is trivial:

```
(def g
  {:phone [:mobilephone]
   :mobilephone [:touchscreen :keyboard]
   :touchscreen [:camera :product]
   :keyboard [:camera :product]
   :camera [:highrescam :lowrescam]
   :highrescam [:flash]
   :lowrescam [:flash]
   :flash [:product]})
```

Again, the model in yEd:
[image]

As expected, introducing a new binary option doubles the number of paths:

```
(all-paths g :phone :product)

([:phone :mobilephone :touchscreen :camera :highrescam :flash :product]
 [:phone :mobilephone :touchscreen :camera :lowrescam :flash :product]
 [:phone :mobilephone :touchscreen :product]
 [:phone :mobilephone :keyboard :camera :highrescam :flash :product]
 [:phone :mobilephone :keyboard :camera :lowrescam :flash :product]
 [:phone :mobilephone :keyboard :product])
```

Bringing it all back, Neo4j offers an [`allPaths` algorithm](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html) if you decide you need a database after all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case im not seeking for paths. For example you can have a model in which you can have both camera types (components at the same level)

I have a feature model and from that model you can generate a traces tree and traverse it to get the products.